# Image correlation

Tags: image-processing, image

I have two images from motor scan, Image1 is shifted by MxN pixels from Image2. How can I find the shift between Image1 and Image2 ?

Image -1 
[image: 1]
Image -2
[image: 2]

If we compare the shift between the images in terms of {X,Y} I will be able to tell how many steps of the motor scan corresponds to the pixel shift on the image array sensor.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation - dont know if there is a buitin mathematica procedure though or if you need to roll your own.

Comment: All answers are equally good. It wouldn't be right if I choose one of them as the right answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many different image registration algorithms, all with different advantages and disadvantages. But I usually try the simplest choice first: I simply pass the two images to `ImageCorrelate`.

```
img1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/laZeT.png"];
img2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAHyF.png"];
corr = ImageAdjust[ImageCorrelate[img1, img2, EuclideanDistance]]
```

[image]

Intuitively, `ImageCorrelate` shifts `img2` by every possible offset, calculates the difference with `img1` with that offset, and stores the difference in the output image. So the pixel location with the lowest value in this image corresponds to the offset that minimizes the difference:

```
minOffset = PixelValuePositions[corr, Min[ImageData[corr]]][[1]] - 
   ImageDimensions[img1]/2;
FlipView[{ImageTransformation[img1, TranslationTransform[minOffset ], 
   PlotRange -> Full], img2}]
```

[image]

If you look at the result of `ImageCorrelate`, you can see that there's one global minimum. That's the offset where the "U" shapes in the two images are aligned. There's a second local minimum left of it; That's probably where the left "leg" of one U is aligned with the right leg of the other. The shape of the correlation function around the global minimum and the relative correlation values at the local minima give a qualitative impression of the accuracy and reliability of the alignment.

`EuclideanDistance` compares brightness values. So the different overall brightness in the two images can "move" the minimum. If you don't want that, you can apply a filter to the images that basically removes the low-frequency background lighting changes:

```
filter = LaplacianGaussianFilter[#, 25] &;
corr = ImageAdjust[
  ImageCorrelate[filter[img1], filter[img2], CosineDistance]]
```

[image]

(where `25` is roughly the width of the U-shape. Details smaller than that and low-frequency changes larger than that are removed by the LoG filter.)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanations - they're very useful for learning about image-processing. Your value is `{-140, -12}`, @s.s.o's is `{149.983, 16.172}` to `{146.53, 15.249}`, @belisarius' is `{146.587, 14.2423}`, - mine is a bit off at {150.42, 30.8978}. My two manual attempts (using Get Coordinates) were at the lower end of this range, agreeing with yours.

Comment: Can you explain why it is necessary to use `ImageDimensions[img1]/2` in order to get the correct amount to translate the second image?

Comment: @olliepower: because the position I've found is the center of the found position, and `TranslationTransform` wants the top-left corner position. Hence `-ImageDimensions[]/2`

Answer (score 8):

I think `ImageCorrespondingPoints` is a good use of what you need. You can improve the results by more preprocessing steps. You can also check `ImageFeatureTrack` and `FindGeometricTransform`.

```
img1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/laZeT.png"];
img2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAHyF.png"];
(*preprocess images*)
images = {DeleteSmallComponents@Binarize[img1, .2], 
  DeleteSmallComponents@Binarize[img2, .2]};
(*find matching points*)
matches = 
 ImageCorrespondingPoints[images[[1]], images[[2]], 
  "Transformation" -> "Translation"];
(*Show points on images*)
MapThread[
 Show[#1, Graphics[{Cyan, 
     MapIndexed[Inset[#2[[1]], #1] & , #2]}]] &, {images, matches}]
```

> {{{351.461, 337.156}}, {{501.884, 358.838}}}

[image]

**Edit 1**

You can also use the option  `"Transformation" -> "Similarity"` which adjusts translation, rotation, and scaling of the images.

```
images = {DeleteSmallComponents@Binarize[FillingTransform@img1, .2], 
   DeleteSmallComponents@Binarize[FillingTransform@img2, .2]};
matches = 
 ImageCorrespondingPoints[images[[1]], images[[2]], 
  "Transformation" -> "Similarity"]
Show[ImageAssemble[images], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.02], 
   MapThread[
    If[#2 === Missing[], {Cyan, Point[#1]}, 
      Arrow[{#1, #2 + {ImageDimensions[img1][[1]], 0}}]] &, 
    matches]}]]
```

> {{{353.43, 359.493}, {377.258, 359.066}}, {{503.413, 
>      375.665}, {523.788, 374.315}}}

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here you have the transformation function for the images:

```
{i1, i2} = Import@# & /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/laZeT.png", 
                          "https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAHyF.png"};  
ch = ChanVeseBinarize /@ {i1, i2};
dsc = FillingTransform /@ (DeleteSmallComponents[#, 5000] & /@ ch);
pts = ImageCorrespondingPoints[dsc[[1]], dsc[[2]]];
f   = FindGeometricTransform[pts[[1]], pts[[2]], "Transformation" -> "Translation", Method->"RANSAC"]
GraphicsGrid@{{i1, ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i2, f[[2]], DataRange -> Full]}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The coefficients of the translation are:

> {
>    {-146.587},
>    {-14.2423}
>   }

Here you can see how the images overlap after the transformation (Thanks to Simon for the idea)

```
ColorCombine[{EdgeDetect[dsc[[1]]], 
              ImagePerspectiveTransformation[EdgeDetect[dsc[[2]]], f[[2]], 
              DataRange -> Full]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nicely done. You can use `ColorCombine[{i1, 
  ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i2, f[[2]], DataRange -> Full]}]` to show how well they overlap.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks! I modified your idea slightly to get a (I think) less cluttered image

Comment: Why do you use ChanVeseBinarize ? Is it to adjusts the levels in image, rescaling them to cover the range 0 to 1 ?

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use component measurements. But I don't think this will give very accurate results, because the two images are not so similar in many ways, and the images are hard to 'prepare', having a lot of noise. Anyway, it's good to show approaches that don't work so well... :)

```
{i1, i2} = 
 Erosion[DeleteSmallComponents[
     ChanVeseBinarize[#, TargetColor -> Gray]], 10] & /@ {image1, image2}
c1 = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[i1, "MinimalBoundingBox"];
c2 = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[i2, "MinimalBoundingBox"];
```

To see some results:

```
Show[
ImageCompose[image1, {image2, .5}],
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], White, Polygon[c1], Polygon[c2], Green, 
 Text[#, #] & /@ c1, Text[#, #] & /@ c2}]]
```

[image: composition]

The best 'pair' of coordinates here are the rightmost corners, giving the translation from image1 to image2 as:

```
{150.42, 30.8978}
```

which sadly is only approximately close to Belisarius' result.