# Black line after ImageTrim

Tags: image-processing, bugs

as shown in [Image correlation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35226/image-correlation) I would like to detect the shift between a stack of images. Here are the images:

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

and here the code:

```
{i1, i2} = {Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2QWw.png"], 
 Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NbR9.png"]}
ch = ChanVeseBinarize /@ {i1, i2};
dsc = FillingTransform /@ (DeleteSmallComponents[#, 5] & /@ {ch[[1]], 
  ColorNegate[ch[[2]]]});
pts = ImageCorrespondingPoints[dsc[[1]], dsc[[2]]];
f = FindGeometricTransform[pts[[1]], pts[[2]], 
"Transformation" -> "Translation", Method -> "RANSAC"]
GraphicsGrid@{{i1, 
ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i2, f[[2]], DataRange -> Full]}}
```

Unfortunately, applying `ImageTrim` leaves a black line at the edge:

```
ImageTrim[
 ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i2, f[[2]], 
 DataRange -> Full], {{f[[2, 1, 1, 3]], 
 f[[2, 1, 2, 3]]}, {ImageDimensions[i1][[1]], 
 ImageDimensions[i1][[2]]}}]
```

[image: trimmed]

Does anybody knows a solution for this problem?

Comment: No black line for me on _v8_: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IUSBz.png).

Comment: I confirm the black line in v.10.0.0 and no black line in v.8.0.4 under Win7 x64.

Comment: Hmm, I get no corresponding points from `ImageCorrespondingPoints` in V9.0.1 (Mac) and a thick black line in V8.0.4: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wQEK7.png

Comment: Bug still appears present in version 10.0.1

Comment: bug still present in 10.0.2

Answer (score 3):

This should solve the problem:

```
ImagePad[ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i2, Round[f[[2]][[1]]], 
DataRange -> Full], -BorderDimensions[
ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i2, Round[f[[2]][[1]]], 
DataRange -> Full]]]
```