# How to combine a plot with an image

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have an external data file [data](http://www.mediafire.com/download/9e1osk1p25qqvz5/NGC_1566.out) which contains the position of stars of a galaxy simulations and it looks like this

```
data = Import["NGC_1566.out", "Table"];
L0 = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
     PlotStyle -> {Darker[Green], PointSize[0.001]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-60, 60}, {-60, 60}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

and here is a real image of the NGC 1566

[image]

Now I would like to plot and fit my data on top of the real image. Any suggestions?

Comment: [`ImageCompose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCompose.html) and some adjustments to the size and aspectratio of your plot should get you there.

Comment: @Karsten7. Great thanks! BTW, could you elaborate a little bit more your suggestions in a short answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the image of your plot

```
graph = With[{grImp = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/KffdP.jpg"]},
            ColorReplace[grImp, First@DominantColors@grImp -> Transparent]
            ];
```

and the image

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WFIL.jpg"];
```

One can prepare a composition interactively using

```
Manipulate[Module[{irGra},
  irGra = ImageResize[graph, {s1, s2}];
  ImageCompose[img, irGra, Scaled[{p1, p2}]]
  ],
 {{p1, 0.448}, 0.3, 0.8}, {{p2, 0.495}, 0.3, 0.8}, {{s1, 347.5}, 200, 500}, {{s2, 298.}, 200, 500}
 ]
```

[image: ImageComposition]

Comment: `ImageCorrelate` like, e.g. in the answers to this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35226/18476), could be used to find the correct position.

Comment: Just a minor question: at the end, how can I export the joined plot in a .jpg format without showing the `Manipulation` controls?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Right click -> Save Image As... . If you want to use the composed image later in your notebook, e.g. for `Export`, than you can simply `Set` (`=`) it to a global symbol inside of `Manipulate`, e.g. `ic = ImageCompose[img, irGra, Scaled[{p1, p2}]]`.

Answer (score 5):

One more way will be to use `Prolog` option with `ListPlot`. In that case we can use your image as a texture in the background too!

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WFIL.jpg"];
plotRange={{-60, 60}, {-60, 60}};
bdbox = Flatten[MapAt[Reverse, Outer[List, ##], 2], 1] & @@ plotRange;
back = {Texture[image], EdgeForm[],Polygon[bdbox, 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1/5.5, 1/5.5}, {1/5.5,4.4/5.5},
{4.4/5.5, 4.4/5.5}, {4.4/5.5, 1/5.5}}]};
```

Then we can call your `ListPlot`. You can play with the `VertexTextureCoordinates` using `Manipulate` for example to hit the right zoom you need. I set the numbers above from my visual judgement only.

```
data = Import["NGC_1566.out", "Table"];
L0 = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Darker[Green],Axes -> False,
PlotStyle -> {Darker[Green], PointSize[0.001]},PlotRange ->plotRange,
AspectRatio -> 1,ImageSize -> 600, Prolog -> back, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not an excellent fit, but close:

```
L0 = ListPlot[data, Frame->True, Axes->False, PlotStyle -> {Darker[Green],PointSize[0.001]},
  PlotRange -> 1.9 * {{-60,60},{-60,60}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

and, with `im` as the JPEG :

```
ImageCompose[im, L0, {270, 290}]
```

[image]

but the credit goes to [Karsten](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56570/how-to-combine-a-plot-with-an-image#comment162285_56570), not me!