# How to use an image as a plot background

Tags: plotting, image, style

Is it possible to use an image as a plot background?

Comment: I would say something like `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Prolog -> {Rasterize[RandomImage[], "Graphics"]}]` but that seems to error out... Anyone have any idea if it actually is invalid?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One can use [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) to create a background for a `Plot`.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 Prolog -> Inset[RandomImage[UniformDistribution[{.2, .6}], ColorSpace -> "Grayscale", 
    ImageSize -> Full]], PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 AxesStyle -> White]
```

[image: Out]

Comment: Even [works for 3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124178/18476).