# How to stitch two images together

Tags: image-processing

I have talk about how to catenate two images whose have same part totally in my [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109196/how-to-merge-several-partially-overlapping-screenshots-into-one-image).

But in this case two images have similar information, not totally same.

```
img1 = Import @ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc1L8.jpg"
```

[image]

```
img2 = Import @ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGTBv.jpg"
```

[image]

This is my expected result

[image]

If I use `ImageAlign`, I just can see the second image. How to catenate the first image?

```
img3 = ImageAlign[img1, img2];
ImageCompose[img3, {img1, .5}]
```

[image]

I can use `ImageCorrespondingPoints` to see the corresponding points

```
matches = ImageCorrespondingPoints[##] & @@ images;
MapThread[
  Show[#1, Graphics[{Red, MapIndexed[Inset[#2[[1]], #1] & , #2]}], 
    ImageSize -> 400] &, {images, matches}];
dim = ImageDimensions[First[images]];
pos = {First[matches], {First[dim], 0} + # & /@ 
    RescalingTransform[
      Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[Last[images]]}], 
      Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[First[images]]}]][
     Last[matches]]};
Show[ImageAssemble[{First[images], ImageResize[Last[images], dim]}], 
 Epilog -> {Thick, 
   Riffle[MapThread[Line@*List, pos], 
    Unevaluated[RandomColor[]], {1, -1, 2}]}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

But I don't know how to connect them.

Comment: This *VERY* well-studied problem is called "image stitching" or "image compositing." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Mathematica recompose an image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117892/can-mathematica-recompose-an-image)

Comment: @mattiav27 NoNoNo,please cancel the duplicate tag,because those image have **same** part in that post,but in my this post,this two images just have **similar** part.

Comment: @Kuba Need your privilege here,if you agree with my comment upstair

Comment: @yode in order to do what?

Comment: @Kuba I mean this not  a duplicate question..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
padded = ImagePad[img1, {{#, #}, {#2, #2}} & @@ ImageDimensions@img2];
aligned = ImageAlign[padded, img2];


ImageCrop @ ImageCompose[padded, aligned]
```

[image]

Padding may be expensive for `ImageAlign` so if you know where it should fit you can pad from one or two sides not around.

Comment: Fun..it is a magic.I cannot imagine it can be solve by such simple method..

Comment: And there I was messing about with `ImageCorrespondingPoints`.

Comment: @aardvark2012 Don't blame yourself, I don't understand why this is not more straightforward. I mean, this is an obvious thing to want for two images, why would anyone want to crop the second one?

Answer (score 33):

Can supplement Kuba's nice answer with a geometric transform from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeometricTransform.html).

```
 {w, h} = ImageDimensions[img2];
{e, tr} = FindGeometricTransform[img1, img2];
tmp = ImagePerspectiveTransformation[img2, tr, DataRange -> Full, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, First@tr[{w, 0}]}, {0, h}}];
ImageCompose[tmp, {img1, 1}, Round@({w, h}/2)]
```

yielding:

[image]

Comment: Neat and faster :) +1