# How to use OpenCVLink

Tags: image-processing, librarylink

Since [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) provide C++ API,and the *Mathemtica* provide so [many method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CLanguageInterface.html) to connect C++. I think we can call it with our *Mathematica*. The OpenCV provide many powerfull function for image-processing. It can help us a lot.

As the [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39252816#39252816),*Mathematica* provide such directory,maybe contain a ready-made link in

```
FileNameJoin[{$TopDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "OpenCVLink"}]
```

And I can use some function with one argument,such as `OpenCVLink`Private`$Dilation`

```
<< OpenCVLink`
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
OpenCVLink`Private`$Dilation[img, 2]
```

But I don't know how to use other function such as `` OpenCVLink`Private`$HoughCircles `` or `stitcher.stitch` in `opencv_stitching310.dll` for [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155093/how-to-connect-two-images). And I don't think this is a right way to call it since it include a `` Private` ``.Can anyone can tell me more?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there are any public functions there. But here's a way to find all of the `LibraryFunction`: ``Pick[Names["OpenCVLink`Private`*"],
 MatchQ[{_ :> _LibraryFunction}] /@
  
  ToExpression[Names["OpenCVLink`Private`*"], StandardForm, 
   OwnValues]
 ]``. This listing seems reasonable.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks,but I think since the context contain `Private`.I think it is not a open solution..

Comment: The private simply means it's free to change at whim. But that's the case with all the undocumented functionality we use. Core `OpenCVLink` is distributed in the `Links` directory, not as a paclet, so it should be stable at least *within* versions and, probably, between point releases.

Comment: @b3m2a1 These [file name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Ago.png) show this OpenCVLink include a complete 3.1.0 version.[Your method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155097/how-to-use-opencvlink?noredirect=1#comment413984_155097) just show a part of the `opencv_core310.dll` I think..

Comment: Look at ``OpenCVLink`Private`InitOpenCVLink``. It shows you how you can load new functions from the links (i.e. through `safeLibraryFunctionLoad` after sticking all the library files on the `LibraryPath`). The ones I provided are the ones they load by default.

Comment: From Mathematica, you would *only* be able to call the library functions as listed in `InitOpenCVLink` as pointed out by b3m2a1. There is no LibraryLink interface implemented for every single OpenCV function. As for how to call `$HoughCircles`, it shouldn't be difficult to figure out from the OpenCV documentation what is the meaning of the four real and two integer parameters: `dp`, `minDist`, `param1`, `param2`, `minRadius` and `maxRadius` in that order.

Comment: @b3m2a1 The fact that it is located under Links does not mean it cannot be paclet-updated if desired -- the paclet manager would simply use the highest version available, which could be a downloaded one.

Comment: @ilian Of course, but I figure an update would be unlikely to remove functionality altogether. The link won't disappear arbitrarily is what I was getting at.

Comment: @ilian I think our *Mathematica* can load any function in a dll file before this.And I hope so.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of something you can do with this. Not having seen ilian's comment, all I did was accessed the private `LibraryFunction`, looked at its parameters, looked at [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) and guessed from there at the parameters.

```
houghCircles[img_,
  dp : _?NumericQ : 5,
  minDist : _?NumericQ | Scaled[_?NumericQ] : Scaled[.25],
  cannyThreshold : _?NumericQ : 100,
  accumulatorThreshold : _?NumericQ : 100,
  minRadius : _Integer : 0,
  maxRadius : _Integer : 0
  ] :=
 (
  Needs["OpenCVLink`"];
  Partition[
   OpenCVLink`Private`$HoughCircles[
    Image[
     First@ColorSeparate@
       ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"],
     "Byte"
     ],
    dp,
    Replace[minDist,
     Scaled[i_] :> ImageDimensions[img][[2]]*i
     ],
    cannyThreshold, accumulatorThreshold,
    minRadius, maxRadius
    ],
   3
   ]
  )

imageHoughCircleAnnotate[
  img_,
  houghParams___
  ] :=
 With[{hCs = houghCircles[img, houghParams]},
  Graphics[
   {
    Inset[Image[img, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]], Center, 
     Center, ImageDimensions[img]],
    {
       {Green, Circle[Most[#], 3]},
       {Red, Circle[Most[#], Last[#]]}
       } & /@ hCs
    },
   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img],
   PlotRange -> Thread[{0, ImageDimensions[img]}],
   AspectRatio -> Full
   ]
  ]
```

Beware that I'm pretty sure my annotation function is garbage though. I just did this to see how it worked:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV2Hz.jpg"];

imageHoughCircleAnnotate[img]
```

[image: garbage output]

I'm sure with a bit more doc reading it could be made not garbage though

Comment: garbage indeed.Sorry for laugh about that result image. :)

Comment: @yode I'm not offended at all. I think that function took a total of 5 minutes to spit out, including docs reading.